# Finding a abstraction for repetitive code: Bootstrap analysis

Tags: python, numpy, refactoring

## Intro

There is a pattern that I use all the time in my Python code which analyzes
numerical data. All implementations seem overly redundant or very cumbersome or
just do not play nicely with NumPy functions. I'd like to find a better way to
abstract this pattern.

## The Problem / Current State

A method of statistical error propagation is the bootstrap method. It works by
running the same analysis many times with slightly different inputs and look at
the distribution of final results.

To compute the actual value of `ams_phys`, I have the following equation:

```
ams_phys = (amk_phys**2 - 0.5 * ampi_phys**2) / aB - amcr
```

All the values that go into that equation have a statistical error associated
with it. These values are also computed from other equations. For instance
`amk_phys` is computed from this equation, where both numbers also have
uncertainties:

```
amk_phys_dist = mk_phys / a_inv
```

The value of `mk_phys` is given as (494.2 ± 0.3) in a paper. What I now do is
*parametric bootstrap* and generate `R` samples from a Gaussian distribution
with mean 494.2 and standard deviation 0.3. This is what I store in
`mk_phys_dist`:

```
mk_phys_dist = bootstrap.make_dist(494.2, 0.3, R)
```

The same is done for `a_inv` which is also quoted with an error in the
literature. Above equation is then converted into a list comprehension to yield
a new distribution:

```
amk_phys_dist = [mk_phys / a_inv
                 for a_inv, mk_phys in zip(a_inv_dist, mk_phys_dist)]
```

The first equation is then also converted into a list comprehension:

```
ams_phys_dist = [
    (amk_phys**2 - 0.5 * ampi_phys**2) / aB - amcr
    for ampi_phys, amk_phys, aB, amcr
    in zip(ampi_phys_dist, amk_phys_dist, aB_dist, amcr_dist)]
```

To get the end result in terms of (Value ± Error), I then take the average and
standard deviation of this distribution of numbers:

```
ams_phys_val, ams_phys_avg, ams_phys_err \
        = bootstrap.average_and_std_arrays(ams_phys_dist)
```

The actual value is supposed to be computed with the actual value coming in,
not the mean of this bootstrap distribution. Before I had the code replicated
for that, now I have the original value at the 0th position in the `_dist`
arrays. The arrays now contain `1 + R` elements and the
`bootstrap.average_and_std_arrays` function will separate that element.

This kind of line occurs for every number that I might want to quote in my
writing. I got annoyed by the writing and created a snippet for it:

```
$1_val, $1_avg, $1_err = bootstrap.average_and_std_arrays($1_dist)
```

The need for the snippet strongly told me that I need to do some refactoring.
Also the list comprehensions are always of the following pattern:

```
foo_dist = [ ... bar ...
            for bar in bar_dist]
```

It feels bad to write `bar` three times there.

## The Class Approach

I have tried to make those `_dist` things a `Boot` class such that I would not
write `ampi_dist` and `ampi_val` but could just use `ampi.val` without having
to explicitly call this `average_and_std_arrays` functions and type a bunch of
names for it.

```
class Boot(object):
    def __init__(self, dist):
        self.dist = dist

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.dist)

    @property
    def cen(self):
        return self.dist[0]

    @property
    def val(self):
        x = np.array(self.dist)
        return np.mean(x[1:,], axis=0)

    @property
    def err(self):
        x = np.array(self.dist)
        return np.std(x[1:,], axis=0)
```

However, this still does not solve the problem of the list comprehensions. I
fear that I still have to repeat myself there three times. I could make the
`Boot` object inherit from `list`, such that I could at least write it like
this (without the `_dist`):

```
bar = Boot([... foo ... for foo in foo])
```

## Magic Approach

Ideally all those list comprehensions would be gone such that I could just
write

```
bar = ... foo ...
```

where the dots mean some non-trivial operation. Those can be simple arithmetic
as above, but that could also be a function call to something that does not
support being called with multiple values (like NumPy function do support).

For instance the `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` function needs to be called a bunch of times:

```
popt_dist = [op.curve_fit(linear, mpi, diff)[0]
             for mpi, diff in zip(mpi_dist, diff_dist)]
```

One would have to write a wrapper for that because it does not automatically loops over list of arrays.

## Question

Do you see a way to abstract this process of running every transformation with
`1 + R` sets of data? I would like to get rid of those patterns and the huge
number of variables in each namespace (`_dist`, `_val`, `_avg`, ...) as this
makes passing it to function rather tedious.

Still I need to have a lot of freedom in the `... foo ...` part where I need to
call arbitrary functions.

Comment: I seem to be missing something trivial here: why can't you use `amk_phys_dist = np.array(mk_phys_dist) / np.array(a_inv_dist)` ? You can also use np.tolist() if you must have them as lists for some reason.

Comment: @VBB: Sure, that would work for that example. Bot it would not work for `popt_dist = [op.curve_fit(linear, mpi, diff)[0] for mpi, diff in zip(mpi_dist, diff_dist)]` because `mpi` and `diff` are already of type `np.array` and `curve_fit` does not loops over the lists of arrays automatically.

Comment: Have you looked at `np.vectorize` for `op.curve_fit`?